# Processing unmanageable CPU cost when a video is loaded using video library

Tags: processing, cpu-usage, movie

I'm trying to do a simple think: when a button is pressed i load a video using the processing video library, each button is associated with a different video, for example button 1 with video 1, button 2 with video 2, and so on. The code works but every time I call a video, also the same i have already load, rewriting the gloabal variable the consume of CPU grows, reaching the 40% after the thrid loading, after 7 video the consume of CPU is near the 100%. An extraction of the code:

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie movie;
void setup() {
    size(1280, 720, P3D);
    background(0);
}
void draw() {
    //image(movie, 0, 0, width, height);

    if (but1_1==1) {
       println("video 1");
       movie = new Movie(this, "1.mp4"));
       movie.loop();
       movie.volume(0);
  }
  if (but1_2==1) {
       println("video 2");
       movie = new Movie(this, "2.mp4"));
       movie.loop();
       movie.volume(0);
  }
  if (but1_3==1) {
       println("video 3");
       movie = new Movie(this, "3.mp4"));
       movie.loop();
       movie.volume(0);
  }
}
```

As you can see, it should not be any reason in based on which the CPU consume grows: the instantiated object movie is always rewritten every time a new video (or the same) is loaded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the movies in loop, which means they don't stop. So the more buttons you press, the more videos are processed at the same time. On every button press, you should stop the movie-playing-process of the old movie first, before you start a new one.